# Git clone connection time out

Tags: svn

I know this looks like a stupid question but how to download this url? using git?
[svn checkout http://android-playground.googlecode.com/svn/ android-playground-read-only](http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/source/checkout)?

I am trying to download some code of swipey tabs and make it as my reference so I follow some instructions on the net but i cant download it.. it says connection timeout. 
 here is my error on my terminal

```
Cloning into 'SwipeyTabsSample'...
fatal: unable to connect to android-playground.googlecode.com:
android-playground.googlecode.com[0: 173.194.72.82]: errno=Connection timed out
android-playground.googlecode.com[1: 2404:6800:4008:c01::52]: errno=Network is unreachable
```

Comment: No, this is using svn, not git. You need to install subversion.

Comment: aah.. ok i thought svn and git are the same.. Thanks

Comment: @Thilo: while this is truly an SVN URL, there's no need to take anything else but `git svn`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm wondering why nobody mentions `git svn`: you **can** do it using Git: there's [`git svn`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) contained in the standard Git distribution. This takes an SVN repo and clones it into a Git repo:

```
git svn clone http://android-playground.googlecode.com/svn/android-playground-read-only
```

Once cloning is done, you could work on the repo with Git.

Since it's read-only, you'll never going to `git svn dcommit` (push changes back to repo). Check the [man page of `git svn`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) in order to know the further parameters and commands available (e.g. not cloning the full history but only the last revision and so on).

`git svn` has (AFAIK) the problem that it doesn't clone the tags and branches of the SVN repo correctly. In order to achieve this, check [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git).

---

**Epilogue:**
I think you're just starting with revision control and therefore thought that Git and SVN would be the same. If I would start today, I'd pick one RCS that I'm going to use in future. Coming from SVN, I didn't regret switching over to Git a single day.